# How to remove the double border bottom line below the breadcrumb

Tags: css

There are 2 lines shown below the breadcrumbs on all category pages. The border-bottom CSS is set to

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #color
```

Making any changes to margin, padding or the border width makes no changes to the border bottom to just 1 line. Need to know how to make it one line.

Site url: http://www.catholic-collectibles.com/blroandpasa.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't remove the outer `.breadcrumbs` div, the simplest way is to just use

```
.breadcrumbs .breadcrumbs { border: none }
```

Guaranteed you won't have any extra lines no matter how many other `.breadcrumbs` you have inside the outer `.breadcrumbs` div.

Answer (score 0):

The style you described is set for .breadcrumbs, and you have two nested divs with this class, so the style is applied to both. Either remove the class from one of those elements, or change the style definition to only apply to the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <a href="index.html"> Home</a>
        <a href="shop-by-brand.html">Shop By Brand</a>
        <a href="shop-by-brand-bliss.html">Bliss</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to delete one div or add this css (this css removes the border on the inner .breadcrumb):

```
.breadcrumbs > .breadcrumbs {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can't change the second `.breadcrumbs` class you can do this:

```
.breadcrumbs .breadcrumbs:nth-child(1) {
    border: none;
}
```